# What two digit number is twice the product of its digits

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

**What two digit number is twice the product of its digits**

Is there a way to solve this problem purely algebraically? I was able to solve it by inspection (I got 36). I have been working at it for an hour or so, any ideas? As in, solving as a system of equations

It should be the solution to $ 10a+b = 2ab $

Comment: I found $18$. Are there others?

Comment: 36 and  18 were the only ones I could find. I want to know if there is a way to solve as a system of equations

Comment: The sum of digits of $36$ is $9$ and twice that is $18$, so $36$ is not a solution

Comment: Wait, I misphrased the problem, let me fix it

Comment: @fleablood he changed the problem.

Comment: $10 a = b (2a - 1)$, then $5 | b$ or $5 | 2 a-1$, then the first case only has $b = 0$ or $b = 5$, which leaves $a = 0$ and $b = 0$. The second case $a = 3$ and $a = 8$ are the only choice

Comment: Okay so $x = 10a + b$ and $10a + b = 2ab$ so $5a + \frac b2=ab$ so $b$ is even. Let $b = 2c$ then $5a + c = 2ac$  so $5a = (2a-1)c$ and $\frac {(2a-1)c}a = 5$.  The $a$ and $2a-1$ are relatively prime so $a|c$.  Let $c = ka$ so we have $\frac {(2a-1)ak}a =2(a-1)k=5$ but $5$ is primes so either $2a-1=1; a=1; k=5;c=5; b=10$ or $k=1; 2a-1=5; a=3;c=3;b=6$.  As $b \le 9$ the first is out and $x=10a + b =36$.

Comment: This can be solved using something like [Simon's favorite factoring trick](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Simon%27s_Favorite_Factoring_Trick). In particular, we get $2ab - 10a - b = 0 \;\to\; (2ab - 10a - b + 5) - 5 = 0 \;\to\; (2a - 1)(b - 5) = 5$. I trust you can finish the rest.

Comment: Notice how in both cases the sum of digits is 9. I wonder if that's just a coincidence...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the 2 digit num is $ab$ then $10a+b=2ab$ and so $(2a-1)(b-5)=5$. This forces $b-5=1$ (since $b-5<5$) and $2a-1=5$ so that $ab=36$.

Comment: See the edit I made

Comment: Ok now see answer. @jizert

Comment: I agree with this solution. Very nice. Although to avoid confusion. the last phrase should be, "so that the two-digit number is $10a+b=36$" because $ab = 18,$ not $36.$

Comment: ab = 36 because $ 3 \cdot 6 = 18 $ and $ 18 \cdot 2 = 36 $

Comment: @jizert no: $ab = (3)(6)=18.\quad 2ab = 36.$

Answer (score 1):

$10a+b=2ab\implies b=\frac{10a}{2a-1}.$

Since $2a-1$ is odd, $2a-1|a$ or $2a-1|5.$ So $a=3$.

Comment: I misphrased the problem, I just fixed it

Comment: @jizert Wasnt it too late for change?

Answer (score 1):

The question right now is which two-digit integer is twice the product of its digits.  That will be a solution to $10a + b = 2ab$.

Solving for $b$ gives $b = 10a/(2a-1)$; alternately, solving for $a$ gives $a = b/(2b-10)$.  I see a nice way to rewrite the first one.

We can rewrite the solution for $b$ as $$b = 5 + {5 \over 2a-1}$$

and for this to be an integer we need $2a-1$ to be a factor of 5. There are two possibilities:

- $2a-1 = 1$ gives $a = 1, b = 10$, and indeed $1(10)$ would be a solution if $(10)$ were a single digit, but it's not.
- $2a-1 = 5$ gives $a = 3, b = 6$, and the solution $36$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the equation
$$10a+b=2a+2b$$,
then $8a=b$, so there is only 18.

Comment: I misphrased the problem, I just fixed

Answer (score 0):

The solution to $10a + b = 2a + 2b$ is only $18$, unless $0$ is counted as a two digit number $00$ (which is obviously nitpicking, almost like playing a card game with your cousin, he invents new rules on the spot).

Rearranging, $8a = b$, thus the only digit solutions are $(0, 0)$ and $(1, 8)$.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so $x = 10a + b$ and $10a + b = 2ab$ so $5a + \frac b2=ab$ so $b$ is even. Let $b = 2c$ then $5a + c = 2ac$  so $5a = (2a-1)c$ and $\frac {(2a-1)c}a = 5$.  The $a$ and $2a-1$ are relatively prime so $a|c$.  Let $c = ka$ so we have $\frac {(2a-1)ak}a =2(a-1)k=5$ but $5$ is primes so either $2a-1=1; a=1; k=5;c=5; b=10$ or $k=1; 2a-1=5; a=3;c=3;b=6$.  As $b \le 9$ the first is out and $x=10a + b =36$.

Kinda kooky but ... there you have it.

===

Okay ... maybe simpler.  Divide both sides by $b$.

$10a + b = 2ab$

$10 +\frac ba = 2b$.  This tells us $a\mid b$ so let $b=ka$ and we get

$10 + k = 2ka$ and so

$10 = (2a=1)k$.

So $2a-1$ is an odd factor of $10$.  So two cases:

$2a-1=1; a=1; k=10; b=10$ which is impossible as $b < 10$

or $2a-1=5; a=3;k = 2; b=6$ so $x =10a + 6 = 36$.